# Question about Sharepoint Permissions and Editing File Names

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin

If I turn off a permission group's ability to delete files, does it also prevent them from editing the names of files?

Answer (score 1):

No. It will not prevent them from editing name of a file.

If you remove Delete Items from permission level, keeping Edit items as it is, then they will able to edit the file name.